# Send multiple updates in AtTask PUT request

Tags: api, rest, attask

I am wondering if whether in the API for AtTask there is a method for posting multiple updates in a single URL request.

As an example, I need to update the extRefIDs on 1,000 records. Do I make 1,000 calls to the API (expensive in terms of overhead), or can I send a single request with a JSON or XML payload that contains something like this:

`{data
    {id:1234,extRefID:xx}
    {id:1235,extrefID:xy}
    }`

etc? Would certainly be less overhead on both systems if there was a method for this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Perhaps something like request batching, a la https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Web%20API%20Request%20Batching ?

Comment: I don't think current API can do that. I ended up making thousands of separate calls. It went surprisingly quick though (production faster than testing too).

Comment: Thanks, Geo. I've found the same. I suppose from a RESTful perspective that's the "right" way to go, but the DBA in me is twitching. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do bulk updates on objects of the same type by passing in a single JSON array into the "updates" parameter:

```
PUT .../api/v4.0/task?updates=[{"ID":"abc123","extRefID":"val1"},{"ID":"def456","extRefID":"val2"}]
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks much! This should save a TON of calls.

Comment: I'm getting a 504 when I pass a  large number of requests to the updates parameter. The HTML request looks well formed -- but as soon as it hits 512 bytes (according to Fiddler), I get a 504 gateway timeout. I'll keep fiddling with it, but any thoughts on this behavior?

Comment: I've seen that before when using a GET request, or when putting all the update data in the URL instead of in the body of a POST/PUT request.  Not sure what language you are using but most languages have a way of setting parameters for POST data that is separate from just specifying it in the URL.

Comment: Well, I got this working for small batches; that will help some. Would be nice to have a better idea why it's failing for large batches.

Comment: @joefox97, did you try Sean's suggestion? It should work as long as your large data is being passed in the body of the PUT/POST rather than the querystring.

Comment: Is that the only thing that belongs in the body, or must I also include the sessionID and other components? I'm guessing the body should look like this:
`updates=[{"ID":"abc123","extRefID":"val1"},{"ID":"def456","extRefID":"val2"}]` ?

Comment: you should be able to leave the session ID in the querystring or put it in the body.