# Is it possible to create multiple projects with one POST to the AtTask API?

Tags: post, attask

I'm looking to create an integration to AtTask which may require creating multiple new projects.  The API docs don't really mention if this is possible or if the Post is a single-shot thing. Is this possible by perhaps posting a JSON array?  Does the API support this?

Answer (score 0):

After referencing this post: [Send multiple updates in AtTask PUT request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21833591/send-multiple-updates-in-attask-put-request) I believe it is possible.

It may look something like

```
PUT .../api/v4.0/task?updates=[{"name":"testing","projectID":"abc123"},{"name":"testing2","projectID":"abc123"}]
```

Comment: Thanks for the link, but after testing various permutations I have come to the conclusion that the API does not support this (specifically on CREATE).  On project create (POST) it seems to require the name parameter and appears to have no capacity for accepting an array of names. (Instead it named my project [{"name:testp1},{"name:testp2}] literally.)  Fortunately it should be rare that I'd need to do this, but will require extra code to do the right thing when I have to.